# "Safe" TO_NUMBER()

Tags: oracle, type-conversion, ora-01722

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('*') FROM DUAL
```

This obviously gives me an exception:

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Is there a way to "skip" it and get `0` or `NULL` instead?

The whole issue: I have `NVARCHAR2` field, which contains numbers and not almost ;-) (like `*`) and I need to select the biggest number from the column.

Yes, I know it is a terrible design, but this is what I need now... :-S

**UPD**:

For myself I've solved this issue with

```
COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(field, '^\d+')), 0)
```

Comment: Is * the only character you'd expect to encounter?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: nope... I've solved this with ugly `REGEXP_SUBSTR(field, '^\d+')`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I couldn't find anything better than this:

```
function safe_to_number(p varchar2) return number is
    v number;
  begin
    v := to_number(p);
    return v;
  exception when others then return 0;
end;
```

Comment: Yep, I also decided to write my own function, a bit different than yours (because `54-3` should become `54`, i did not mention that, sorry).

Comment: You'd better ignore only ORA-01722 here.

Comment: Take into account that [custom pl/sql functions have significant performace overhead](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:60122715103602) that may not be suitable for heavy queries.

Comment: Note the answer below showing how to handle this natively from 12c r2 onwards https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886745/587365

Comment: i agree with milan about ignoring only ORA-01722 and would write `exception when invalid_number then return 0;` instead

Answer (score 60):

From `Oracle Database 12c Release 2` you could use **[TO_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/TO_NUMBER.htm#SQLRF06140)** with `DEFAULT ... ON CONVERSION ERROR`:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('*' DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR) AS "Value"
FROM DUAL;
```

Or `CAST`:

```
SELECT CAST('*' AS NUMBER DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR) AS "Value"
FROM DUAL;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0263932d8ae391d67610ced313a1645f)**

Comment: Excellent solution. And yes confirmed: Release 12.1.0.2.0  - doesn't support this yeet

Answer (score 33):

```
COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(field, '^\d+(\.\d+)?')), 0)
```

will also get numbers with scale > 0 (digits to the right of the decimal point).

Comment: This is a good solution, but the regex should be adjusted for each specific scenario.  This regex might work better: `^\-?\d*\.?\d*$` which allows negative numbers and numbers starting with `.`, and disallows non-numeric trailing characters.  The `^\d+(\.\d+)?` regex yields `1` if `field` contains `1x`, and `0' if `field` contains `0.0.1`, and `0` if `field` contains `0 6`, etc.

Answer (score 12):

```
select COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR( field, '^(-|+)?\d+(\.|,)?(\d+)?$')), 0) from dual;
```

It will convert *123* to **123**, but *123a* or *12a3* to **0**.

Answer (score 7):

Fitting the original question and rather old skool

```
select a, decode(trim(translate(b,'0123456789.',' ')),null,to_number(b),0)  from 
(
    select '1' a, 'not a number' b from dual
    union
    select '2' a, '1234' b from dual
)
```

Comment: @Ronnis, the builtins often are, but as you say, they perform well. Works from around Oracle7 (from memory)

Comment: this will make `543` from the string `54-3`. I did not mention it in the question, but in this case I expect `54` (and that is what my solution with regexp does).

Comment: @zerkins,actually thought it would produce 0 from 54-3, anyway, as I said was answering the original question before comments. Like your final solution though.

Comment: Fails if number contains spaces:

select a, decode(trim(translate(b,'0123456789.',' ')),null,to_number(b),0)  from 
(
    select '1' a, '12 34' b from dual
)

Comment: Couldn't use regex in my application so this worked great

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bit messy rolling your own regexp to test for a number, but the code below might work. I think the other solution by Gabe involving a user defined function is more robust since you are using the built in Oracle functionality (and my regexp is probably not 100% correct) but it might be worth a go:

```
with my_sample_data as (
  select '12345' as mynum from dual union all
  select '54-3' as mynum from dual union all
  select '123.4567' as mynum from dual union all
  select '.34567' as mynum from dual union all
  select '-0.3462' as mynum from dual union all
  select '0.34.62' as mynum from dual union all
  select '1243.64' as mynum from dual 
)
select 
  mynum, 
  case when regexp_like(mynum, '^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$') 
    then to_number(mynum) end as is_num
from my_sample_data
```

This will then give the following output:

```
MYNUM   IS_NUM
-------- ----------
12345   12345
54-3    
123.4567    123.4567
.34567  
-0.3462 -0.3462
0.34.62 
1243.64 1243.64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select DECODE(trim(TRANSLATE(replace(replace(A, ' '), ',', '.'), '0123456789.-', ' ')),
              null,
              DECODE(INSTR(replace(replace(A, ' '), ',', '.'), '.', INSTR(replace(replace(A, ' '), ',', '.'), '.') + 1),
                     0,
                     DECODE(INSTR(replace(replace(A, ' '), ',', '.'), '-', 2),
                            0,
                            TO_NUMBER(replace(replace(A, ' '), ',', '.'))))) A
  from (select '-1.1' A from DUAL union all select '-1-1' A from DUAL union all select ',1' A from DUAL union all select '1..1' A from DUAL) A;
```

This code excludes such strings as: -1-1, 1..1, 12-2 and so on. And I haven't used regular expressions here.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of previous solutions (from @sOliver and @Mike Meyers) and trying to grab as much numbers as possible by removing the last '$' from REGEXP.

It can be used to filter the actual number from a configuration table, and have a "kind-of" comment next to the number as '12 Days'.

`with my_sample_data as (
  select '12345' as mynum from dual union all
  select '123.4567' as mynum from dual union all
  select '-0.3462' as mynum from dual union all
  select '.34567' as mynum from dual union all
  select '-.1234' as mynum from dual union all
  select '**' as mynum from dual union all
  select '0.34.62' as mynum from dual union all
  select '24Days' as mynum from dual union all
  select '42ab' as mynum from dual union all
  select '54-3' as mynum from dual 
)
SELECT mynum,
  COALESCE( TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( mynum, '^(-|+)?\d*(.|,)?(\d+)?') ) , 0) is_num
FROM my_sample_data;`

would give

```
MYNUM    IS_NUM                                  
-------- ----------
12345    12345                                   
123.4567 123.4567                                
-0.3462  -0.3462                                 
.34567   0.34567                                 
-.1234   -0.1234                                 
**       0                                       
0.34.62  0.34                                    
24Days   24                                      
42ab     42                                      
54-3     54
```

Answer (score 0):

Best method seems to be the function solution but if you don't have necessary privileges in the environment you are struggling (like me), then you can try this one:

```
SELECT
 CASE
  WHEN
     INSTR(TRANSLATE('123O0',
                     ' qwertyuıopğüasdfghjklşizxcvbnmöçQWERTYUIOPĞÜASDFGHJKLŞİZXCVBNMÖÇ~*\/(){}&%^#$<>;@€|:_=',
                     'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                     ),
       'X') > 0
  THEN 'Y'
  ELSE 'N'
END is_nonnumeric
FROM DUAL
```

By the way: In my case the problem was due to "," and "." :) So take that into consider. Inspired from [this one](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php). Also [this one](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=determine-whether-the-given-is-numeric-alphanumeric-and-hexadecimal) seems more concise.

By the way 2: Dear Oracle, can you please create some built-in functions for such small but invaluable needs?

Comment: It is present already: [DEFAULT on ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886745/5070879) and [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886915/5070879)