# SQL: if cannot convert to_number set as null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with this values:

```
ID      VALUE
-----------------------
23559   200
23562   -1 & {14376}#-1
```

and I want to do to a select that if I cannot convert to number set NULL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Safe" TO\_NUMBER()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486949/safe-to-number)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I generally use translate for this because it is such an odd corner case:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
     WHEN NOT TRIM(TRANSLATE(COLUMN_NAME, '1234567890', ' ')) IS NULL THEN NULL
     ELSE COLUMN_NAME
  END AS "NUMERIC_COLUMN"
FROM
  TABLE_NAME;
```

If necessary, that can be turned into a procedure, but I'm not sure that there would be terribly much benefit performance-wise.

Comment: +1, I like the non-procedural solution, but shouldn't TRIM(TRANSLATE(COLUMN_NAME, '1234567890', ' ')) IS NULL be TRIM(TRANSLATE(COLUMN_NAME, '1234567890', ' ')) IS NOT NULL?

Comment: A pure translate may have issues with non-integer data (i.e. presumably, 0.99 is a valid number but 0.99.123.4 is not) and with strings that may include grouping separators (i.e. 1,000.00 is probably a valid number).

Comment: Tanks to all for helping in a sort time, the @cwallenpoole worked for me.

Comment: @JustinCave The other option is:
`WHEN TRIM(TRANSLATE(COLUMN_NAME, '1234567890', ' ')) = '.' THEN NULL WHEN TRIM(TRANSLATE(COLUMN_NAME, '1234567890', ' ')) IS NULL THEN NULL`

Comment: @cwallenpoole - That works for a number like '0.99'.  It doesn't work for, say, '1,000.99' since you'd be left with ',.'.

Comment: @JustinCave At that point you need to start building a parsing function.

Answer (score 11):

You can create a function that tries to convert the string to a number and catches the exception.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_to_number( p_str IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  l_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    l_num := to_number( p_str );
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
      l_num := null;
  END;

  RETURN l_num;
END;
```

Then you can

```
SELECT id, my_to_number( value )
  FROM your_table
```

Comment: +1 probable best solution for numbers other than unsigned integers.

Answer (score 9):

You could also use REGEXP_LIKE:

```
SELECT id
     , CASE WHEN regexp_like(value,'^[0-9]+$') THEN TO_NUMBER(value)
            ELSE NULL
        END value
  FROM your_table;
```

For example:

```
SQL> WITH q AS (
  2  SELECT 1 ID, '200' col FROM dual
  3  UNION
  4  SELECT 2, '-1 & {14376}#-1' FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT id, CASE WHEN regexp_like(col,'^[0-9]+$') THEN TO_NUMBER(col) ELSE NULL END TEST FROM q;

        ID       TEST
---------- ----------
         1        200
         2
```

Answer (score 7):

With Oracle 12.**2** this can be done a bit easier using the `on conversion error` option:

```
select id, cast(value as number default null on conversion error) as value
from the_table;
```

Optionally you can also specify [a format mask](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/CAST.htm#SQLRF00613), similar to the `to_number()` function.

I assume this would be faster than using a PL/SQL function, not sure about the performance compared to a `case` with a regex. But it is definitely a lot shorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION asnumber(p_val IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
l_val NUMBER;
BEGIN
   l_val := TO_NUMBER(p_val);
   RETURN l_val;
EXCEPTION WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
   RETURN null;
END;
```