# Oracle PLSQL exception inserting dates

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, oracle11g

I have an `INSERT` statement in a procedure with a date field in NUMBER format converted into DATE, but in some cases the conversion is not possible. I've tried to handle the exception with `EXCEPTION` `WHEN OTHERS THEN` but it doesn't insert any row.

I want to insert `NULL` only in the `DATE` field when conversion is not possible.

Do I have to use any cursor or collection?

Comment: Can you show us the code in your procedure?

Comment: I think you should make your own validation function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486949/safe-to-number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own function like this:

```
create or replace function safe_to_date(p number) return date DETERMINISTIC is
  begin
    return to_date(p, 'yyyymmdd');
  exception 
    when value_error
    then return null;
end;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
select safe_to_date(00000) as test from dual;
TEST   
--------


select safe_to_date(20160826) as test from dual;
TEST   
--------
26.08.16
```

Comment: `to_date` is also recognised by PL/SQL, so there's no need to add a pointless (and performance-affecting) SQL query in there.

Comment: also, don't use `when others` without a raise - instead, use the specific exception you're expecting.