# Oracle update issue with AND operator

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a staging table in oracle, all columns are set to varchar2 to accept text data from excel import functionality. Once the data is bulk copied to staging table, I validate the data & flag errors for records which failed validation.

One of my validation statement throws an error of "Invalid Number". Is there any way to stop oracle from evaluating the right side of AND condition when left side has failed?

My update statement is as below & the AMT columns has text non-numeric data.

```
UPDATE StagingTable
SET ErrorTXT = Error_txt || 'Invalid Amount, '
WHERE f_isnumber (INV_AMT) > 0
AND TO_NUMBER (INV_AMT) > 9999999999.99;
```

INV_AMT column as junk non numeric data. I am expecting the left side of the condition which evaluates to false, for non-numeric data, should stop evaluation of right side & thus Invalid Number error should not be thrown.
Is there any hint I can use?

Comment: Either do two UPDATE, or use a case expression in the WHERE clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486949/safe-to-number

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ON CONVERSION ERROR` with `TO_NUMBER` if you are using Oracle 12.2 or higher as following so that you dont need `f_isnumber` function:

```
UPDATE StagingTable
SET ErrorTXT = Error_txt || 'Invalid Amount, '
WHERE TO_NUMBER(INV_AMT DEFAULT -1 ON CONVERSION ERROR)  > 9999999999.99;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This looks a good option. My version of oracle showing 12.2. But the above statement showing syntax issues on DEFAULT.

Comment: [Error] ORA-43907 (195: 47): PL/SQL: ORA-43907: This argument must be a literal or bind variable. This is the error I see. I am able to use that in select statement though.

Comment: Show me the exact code where you are facing this error. I think you must have used different value or function in default clause

Comment: I am able to run the statement. I guess its throwing that error only during compiling package.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `case` expression.  Assuming the function `f_isnumber()` does this test:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN f_isnumber(INV_AMT) > 0 THEN TO_NUMBER(INV_AMT)
       END) > 9999999999.99;
```

If not, you can use a regular expression:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(INV_AMT, '^-?[0-9]*([.][0-9])?[0-9]*') 
            THEN TO_NUMBER(INV_AMT)
       END) > 9999999999.99;
```